# Oracle Apex Link Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have created an interactive report based on the following SQL

```
SELECT 
      (FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME) NAME,
      (ADDRESS_LINE1 || ', ' || ADDRESS_LINE2 
      || ', ' || CITY || ', ' || POSTCODE) Address,
       ('0' || CONTACT_NUMBER) Phone_Number,
       EMAIL Email_Address,
       ACTIVE Active_Client
FROM CLIENT
```

I would also like to create a link column to edit the data, however, as you can see I have grouped a few fields together into one string. Meaning that when I go to set up the link column I can't add all items to the correct value.

Is it possible to show edit all the data in the correct fields as well as keeping the interactive report in the following format or will I have to use a select all.

Comment: Normally you'd create a separate page to edit the data, and call it with just the record ID as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the fields you wish to use in your link column are present in your interactive report. You can do this in addition to your derived fields, and set the Display Type of the individual fields to Hidden should you wish to.

But the more straightforward solution is as Jeffery Kemp commented, just to use the primary key in your link column and then pull from the database using the primary key when loading your form.

If you create a new page, choose Form, and the "Form on a Table with Report" option, ApEx will do all the hard work for you.